# Unxepected behavour when access to generator object from list in for loop

Tags: python, generator

I have following code:

```
l = [(i for j in xrange(2)) for i in xrange(3)]

print list(l[0])

for i in l:
    print list(i)
```

And following output:

```
[2, 2]

[]

[<generator object <genexpr> at 0x022B97B0>, <generator object <genexpr> at 0x022B97B0>]

[<generator object <genexpr> at 0x022B9D00>, <generator object <genexpr> at 0x022B9D00>]
```

First two lines is expected result, but the last two results looks trange for me.
I suppose there is no difference between accesses by index l[0] or access each element of list in loop via iterator. Could you please help me?

Comment: `l` is a list of *generator* objects, and that's what you're printing.

Answer (score 1):

**This problem is caused by a variable name conflict.** Variable used by list comprehension shares the global namespace instead of using a isolated one in python 2.x. So, change your variable name from `i` to something different will give you the right result.

```
l = [(i for j in xrange(2)) for i in xrange(3)]

print list(l[0])

# Change variable name to `value`
for value in l:
    print list(value)
```

This will print:

```
[2, 2]
[]
[2, 2]
[2, 2]
```

To prove this further, you can do something like this:

```
l = [(i for j in xrange(2)) for i in xrange(3)]

print list(l[0])

i = 'another value'

for value in l:
    print list(value)
```

This will give you:

```
[2, 2]
[]
['another value', 'another value']
['another value', 'another value']
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you've used the variable `i` in your list comprehension, `i` will be something totally different from what you expect.

```
print i
>> 2
```

So changing it for `item` will yield the correct result.

```
for item in enumerate(l):
  list(item)

>> [2, 2]
>> [2, 2]
>> [2, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `i` in the list `l` is not a list of lists but instead it is a reference to a generator object (different in each iteration).

```
>>> l = [(i for j in xrange(2)) for i in xrange(3)]
>>> for i in l:
...     print i
... 
<generator object <genexpr> at 0xb71ed194>
<generator object <genexpr> at 0xb71ed1bc>
<generator object <genexpr> at 0xb71ed1e4>
```

[PEP 0289](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) defines about the `Generator expressions`. It seems quite similar to [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). Quoting directly from PEP 0289:

> "Experience with list comprehensions has shown their wide-spread utility throughout Python. However, many of the use cases do not need to have a full list created in memory. Instead, they only need to iterate over the elements one at a time."

Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756096/understanding-generators-in-python). In your case, try this for instance:

```
l = [(i for j in xrange(2)) for i in xrange(3)]
k = [[i for j in xrange(2)] for i in xrange(3)]

print list(l[0])

for i in l:
    print list(i)
for i in k:
    print list(i)
```

In the above code, `l` is a list of generator objects while `k` is a list of lists.

Now, consider them one by one. First check for the list `l`:

```
>>> l = [(i for j in xrange(2)) for i in xrange(3)]
>>> for i in l:
...     print list(i)
... 
[<generator object <genexpr> at 0xb71c70cc>, <generator object <genexpr> at 0xb71c70cc>]
[<generator object <genexpr> at 0xb71c70a4>, <generator object <genexpr> at 0xb71c70a4>]
[<generator object <genexpr> at 0xb71c71bc>, <generator object <genexpr> at 0xb71c71bc>]
>>> for i in l:
...     print list(i)
... 
[]
[]
[]
```

You can iterate over a generator object only once. But, in other case, we can use as many times as we want.

```
>>> k = [[i for j in xrange(2)] for i in xrange(3)]
>>> for i in k:
...     print list(i)
... 
[0, 0]
[1, 1]
[2, 2]
>>> for i in k:
...     print list(i)
... 
[0, 0]
[1, 1]
[2, 2]
```

But, if you needed a list of tuples then you can use this:

```
>>> l = [tuple(i for j in xrange(2)) for i in xrange(3)]
>>> l
[(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2)]
>>> for i in l:
...     print i
... 
(0, 0)
(1, 1)
(2, 2)
>>> for i in l:
...     print i
... 
(0, 0)
(1, 1)
(2, 2)
```